# DataGridView inside a panel jumps to beginning of list after panel gets scrolled

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, datagridview, panel

I have a DataGridView inside a panel. The scrolling is disabled on the DataGridView but instead is done on the panel. By doing so I achieve pixel based scrolling of the DataGridView. I scroll as following:

```
dgvPanel.AutoScrollPosition = value;
```

However, the problem is that after changing the scroll bar position, if I click on the DataGridView - it jumps back to the beginning of the list. What could cause this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the panel you are using with this one, which overrides the ScrollToControl function the default panel is using to make sure the control is visible:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel {
  protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
    //return base.ScrollToControl(activeControl);
    return this.AutoScrollPosition;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, by default, when child control is focused panel is ensuring that top of it is visible. Clever solution.